# Add a dynamic UI element in R shiny data table

Tags: r, shiny

I am generating a data table with some results. I would like the user to be able to click on a particular row for example to show details. The following setup works:

**ui.R**

```
library(DT)
shinyUI({
  basicPage(
    actionButton("compute", "Compute"),

    tags$div(id="blah", class="shiny-input-radiogroup", 
      dataTableOutput( "results" )
    ), 
    tags$h1(textOutput( "foo" ))
  )
})
```

**server.R**

```
library(DT)
server.fun <- function(input, output) {
  output$foo <- renderText({
    input$blah
  })

  output$results <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$compute) {
      results <- data.frame(ID=1:10, contents=letters[1:10])
      results$checkbox <- sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="blah" value="%d"/>', 1:10 )
      datatable(results, escape=FALSE)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
}
```

When you click on a radio button, an action is taken (the row number get displayed on the bottom). This is nice and demonstrates what I want to achieve. However, I would like to have a regular action button, and not a radio button. The following code does not work, my question: how can I make it work?

**ui.R**

```
library(DT)
shinyUI({
  basicPage(
    actionButton("compute", "Compute"),
    dataTableOutput( "results" ),
    tags$h1(textOutput( "foo" ))
  ) 
})
```

**server.R**

```
library(DT)

server.fun <- function(input, output) {
  output$foo <- renderText({
    input$blah
  })

  output$results <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$compute) {
      results <- data.frame(ID=1:10, contents=letters[1:10])
      results$checkbox <- 
        sprintf( '<button id="blah" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button" value="%d">Do</button>', 1:10 )
      datatable(results, escape=FALSE)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `regular action button` ?

Comment: A button produced with the function actionButton, as shown in the example. Specifically, an entity that, when clicked, will cause an action, but not change its state (unlike a radio button), and which includes a text label.

Comment: Please have a look at this solution: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-checkbox/ - hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. However, this is not very different from the solution I have presented in the first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need it I found the way to make it work the action button inside the table. In this case when '?' is clicked and alert message is displayed. Here's the code:

```
output$factorsTable = DT::renderDataTable(
   DT::datatable({
      factorName <- c('Factor 1', 'Factor 2', 'Factor 3', 'Factor 4', 'Factor 5', 'Factor 6', 'Factor 7', 'Factor 8', 'Factor 9', 'Factor 10')
      factorValues <- c('0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4','0.5','0.6','0.7','0.8','0.9','1')
      helpBtn <- '<button><b>?</b></button>'
      helpButton <- c(helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn,helpBtn)
      factors.data <- data.frame(factorName, factorValues,helpButton)    
      factors.data},    
   colnames = c('Factor','Value',,'Help'),  
   escape = FALSE,
   rownames = FALSE,
   selection= 'single',    
   options = list( searching=FALSE, paging =FALSE,                   
       columnDefs = list(
      list(
       targets=4,
       render=JS(
         "function(data, type, full) {",
         "return '<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" onclick=\"alert(\\''+ full[0] +'\\')\"  href=#/' + '>' + '?' + '</a>';",

         "}"  
       )
     ))
     ),     
  class = "display",
  callback = JS('table.page(0).draw(false);')   
  )  
 )
```