# Reactivity of dynamic number of ui elements

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny web interface, which loads an arbitrary number of datatables from a database and displays them. The approach is very similar to the one proposed here: [Add a dynamic UI element in R shiny data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325899/add-a-dynamic-ui-element-in-r-shiny-data-table).

However, the number of datatables can change while working with the interface and in this case the displayed datatables need to be reloaded. My approach fails with the error message

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :    Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I tried to build a minimal example, which makes the error reproducible:

**model.R**

```
db <- list()
getTables <- function( n ){
  db <<- lapply(seq_len( n ), data.frame, a = 1:2, b = LETTERS[1:2])
  return(db)
}
getTableIndex <- function(){
  seq_along(db)
}
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  db_tables  <- getTables( 3 )
  db_tab_ix  <- getTableIndex()

  output$tabs <- renderUI({
    tables <- lapply( db_tab_ix, function(x){
      tableOutput(paste( "tab", x, sep="_"))
    })
    tagList(tables)
  })

  for( x in db_tab_ix ){
    local({
      output[[paste( "tab", x, sep="_")]] <- renderTable( db_tables[[x]] )
    })
  }
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput( "tabs" ),
    sliderInput( "tabs_no", "Integer:",  min=1, max=3, value=1)
  )
))
```

In this example everything works fine. The problem arises when replacing line 3 of the `server.R` with

```
 db_tables <- getTables( input$tabs_no )
```

i.e. when I try to make the data reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that works, I don't think you really want any of that global assigning stuff:

```
test <- function(){
  db <- list()
  getTables <- function( n ){
    db <- lapply(seq_len( n ), data.frame, a = 1:2, b = LETTERS[1:2])
    return(db)
  }
  shinyApp(
    ui=fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput("tabs" ),
        sliderInput( "tabs_no", "Integer:",  min=1, max=3, value=1)
      )
    ),
    server=function(input, output) {
      db_tables <- reactive({
        return(getTables(input$tabs_no))
      })
      output$tabs <- renderUI({
        tbl<-db_tables()
        tables <- sapply(1:input$tabs_no, function(x){
          renderTable(tbl[[x]])
        })
        tagList(tables)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Is this tested? Because if I try this, the tables are not shown at all? it seems like `getTables` is not called at all.